# Loading subsampled GDX pixmap like when using Android's inSampleSize

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm wondering if there's a way to load a subsampled pixmap in libgdx, similar to specifying `inSampleSize` [when loading a bitmap in Android](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). The aim is obviously to only allocate the amount of heap memory that is absolutely necessary.

Good stuff. Cheers, Aert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real answer, but I couldn't find an answer myself when I ran into this problem.

You can always create an interface and implement it on Android (and other projects). You could implement an AndroidTexture easily with a Bitmap (and use inSampleSize). Of  course, it won't be compatible with libgdx Textures (I couldn't find a way to extend correctly from libgdx textures). This won't hurt that much if you don't use Libgdx's sprites or so, but if you do, don't take this approach. I used this to load images from camera, I didn't have any other choice and I only needed to bind the texture for my shaders.

It is also possible to save your sampled images to a folder and let your app load them by their absolute path (also this should be done android-side).

Note that in the first case it won't be a managed texture, you'll need to handle the realoading yourself.